# Is there any way to make this filter query smaller

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

These are my tables:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class Employee_Job(models.Model):
    employee_f = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_f = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Salary(models.Model):
    employee_job_f = models.ForeignKey(Employee_Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField()

    @property
    def name(self):
    return Employee.objects.filter(id = (
        Employee_Job.objects.filter(id = self.employee_job_f_id ).first().employee_f 
)).first().name
```

This query seems very long to me, I thought `select_related()` should help with this, but it follows foreign keys and return ALL results not the result that is related to THIS instance of Salary.

**Follow up on Willem Van Onsem's answer:**

I added a couple more rows to my tables and I'm using this query in the save() function and suddenly I'm getting this error:

`get() returned more than one` which is a popular error.

I made the query a tad smaller too:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.full_name = Employee_Job.objects.get(
        salary=self
    ).name + " 's salary"
super(salary, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I checked to see what SQL query Django is running behind the scenes and I found the culprit:

```
SELECT [blog_employee_job].[id], [blog_employee_job].[employee_f_id], [blog_employee_job].[job_f_id] FROM [blog_employee_job] LEFT OUTER JOIN [blog_salary]
ON ([blog_employee_job].[id] = [blog_salary].[employee_job_f_id])
WHERE [blog_salary].[id] IS NULL
```

I think `WHERE [blog_salary].[id] IS NULL` is the culprit and I don't understand why and I don't know how to fix this, searched a lot and went through Docs a lot as well.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the Employee_Job model, instead set a ForeignKeykey form Employee to Job , then you can simplify the query too.

Comment: @Sumithran: this probably happens when you *create* the object, since at that time, there is no `Salary` object *yet*. I would strongly advise *not* to use this in the `.save()` method: it is not a good idea to store this as data, it will for example not update if the `Employee` changes its name. By using a property, you have a *single source of truth*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can filter with

```
@property
def name(self):
    Employee.objects.get(
        employee_job__salary=self
    ).name
```

This will retrieve the employee which has a `Employee_Job` that is related to `self` as salary.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Employee_Job`</s> to `EmployeeJob`.